# Как при указании человека получить его ID? Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx,nicka):
    thismember = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, nick = nicka )
    thismember.id
    print(thismember.id)
```

Как сделать, чтобы при указании человека получало ID человека?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать так:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx,nicka):
    thismember = ctx.author.id
    print(thismember.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    print(member.id)
```

Когда вы напишете так `!test @user#122543` то есть пинг человека то сможете получить его айди. Можете даже не делать пинговать его а просто написать его имя, например `!test user`

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True) # создаем команду для бота\
#создаем функцию которая будет получать команду #|Prefix|id|@User|\
async def id(ctx, user: discord.Member): 
print(user.id) #Выводим id пользователя в консоль\
#Создаем переменную, которая будет выводить табличку и время
#когда была вызвана табличка\
embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at) 
embed.add_field(name='ID',value=user.id) # пишем в табличку ID и номер id пользователя\
await ctx.send(embed=embed) #выводим сообщение
```

Пример:

```
Vadik: !id @Vadik
Bot: | ID
     |
     | 684261443285714748
     |
     | Сегодня, в 12:44
```